# Para que serve e como usar o "static"?

Tags: php

Estou com muita dúvida em relação a como usar o "static" em um atributo , se alguém puder me tirar essa dúvida eu agradeceria muito, obrigado.

Comment: static em um classe ou função? tem diferença

Comment: métodos e atributos

Answer (score 1):

Palavra-Chave 'static'

Declarar membros ou métodos de uma classe como estáticos faz deles acessíveis sem precisar instanciar a classe. Um membro declarado como estático não pode ser acessado com um objeto instanciado da classe (embora métodos estáticos podem).

```
Exemplo #1 Exemplo de membro estático

<?php
class Foo
{
    public static $meu_estatico = 'foo';

    public function valorEstatico() {
        return self::$meu_estatico;
    }
}


class Bar extends Foo
{
    public function fooEstatico() {
        return parent::$meu_estatico;
    }
}


print Foo::$meu_estatico . "\n";

$foo = new Foo();
print $foo->valorEstatico() . "\n";
print $foo->$meu_estatico . "\n";      // "Propriedade" Indefinida $meu_estatico

print $foo::$meu_estatico . "\n";
$classname = 'Foo';
print $classname::$meu_estatico . "\n"; // No PHP 5.3.0

print Bar::$meu_estatico . "\n";
$bar = new Bar();
print $bar->fooEstatico() . "\n";
?>
```

Referência: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: Muito obrigado, consegui entender melhor com o seu exemplo, obrigado mesmo !